# Mover várias mensagens para uma pasta utilizando o JavaMail

Tags: java, javamail, imap

Estou querendo refatorar um código de manipulação de e-mail, sei que dá para remover várias mensagens em uma operação só, mas e para mover várias mensagens para determinada pasta, tem como?

Utilizo o protocolo IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim. Implementei uma função para isso, é bem fácil!

```
public void saveMessages(Message[] mArray, String folderName) throws Exception{
      //Primeiro copiamos...
      Folder f = findFolder(folderName);
      currentFolder.copyMessages(mArray, f);

      // Depois removemos do diretório antigo!
      for ( int i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++){
          mArray[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
      }
      currentFolder.expunge();
   }
```

Comment: Pô cara, legal, eu não sabia que dava para passar para um folder de uma só vez várias mensagens, para apagar sim. Obrigado

Comment: poderia por favor postar o código do `findFolder`.

Comment: Olha cara, eu vim do C++ e não sei muito de Java não... Dá uma procurada aí e vê se tem um jeito de achar pastas e depois eu edito a pergunta! `:)`